# CSP refused to load css file but not javascript file

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, nonce

I have an html file with a link to css file bundle and at the bottom of that html file I have a 
div which is a container for all javascript code and a javascript bundle like this

[header excerpt from an auto generated html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLAMs.png)

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./wicket/resource/com.demo.WicketApplication/bundle-ver-54903C08BD33E9FB5DA355BE40331F02.css" nonce="o8ucNjn605sWzLMeVlFgM-kh" />
</head>
```

[body excerpt with javascript file and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5xTK.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/com.demo.WicketApplication/bundle-ver-E39F0FD375F78ED454CD6F59F3C635D4.js" nonce="o8ucNjn605sWzLMeVlFgM-kh"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="wicket-ajax-base-url" nonce="o8ucNjn605sWzLMeVlFgM-kh">
/*<![CDATA[*/
Wicket.Ajax.baseUrl="?1";
/*]]>*/
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="our_callback_url" nonce="o8ucNjn605sWzLMeVlFgM-kh">
/*<![CDATA[*/
our_callback_url = './?1-5.0-test';
/*]]>*/
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="o8ucNjn605sWzLMeVlFgM-kh">
/*<![CDATA[*/
Wicket.Event.add(window, "domready", function(event) { 
tripleview.initMyComponent('#id2', tripleview.postJson.bind(tripleview, "./?1-5.0-test"));
Wicket.Event.publish(Wicket.Event.Topic.AJAX_HANDLERS_BOUND);
;});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

So, when I navigate to my page with open devTools window the first time I get

[I get warnings but no errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9biv.png)

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

But when I close devtools window and reopen it again I get an error

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://localhost:8080/wicket/resource/com.demo.WicketApplication/bundle-ver-54903C08BD33E9FB5DA355BE40331F02.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'nonce-t0wrytDNiwGcyBiQ64Uln-uP'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
```

[error in devtools after reopening devtools window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysmak.png)

My question is why do I get this error only with css file but not javascript file. And why this error happens after I reopen devtools after closing devtools window?

P.S

Chrome version: Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I had same warnings in my project. In my case gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom is AdBlock extention. If you open chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map you will see some information about your extention. In my case it is:

```
{"version":3, <...> "webpack:///../adblock-betafish/alias/include.preload.js",<...>
```

I just turned off AdBlock in "chrome://extensions/" and it helped me.

[image: Disable AdBlock]

You can delete AdBlock extension (or turn it off). I hope it will solve your problem.